# Dual space problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

As we know for the pair of positive real numbers, $1\leq p\leq q< \infty$ with $\frac{1}{p}+ \frac{1}{q}=1$, the dual space of sequence space $l^p$ is $l^q$ and vice versa. Suppose $e_n$ is schauder basis for $l^p$. Now consider any subsequence $n_k$ of the natural numbers and define a space $$l^p_{n_k}=\text{span closure of} ~e_{n_k}~\text{in p norm}$$ Then do we have , dual space of $l^p_{n_k}=l^q_{n_k}$ ?

Comment: $l^p_{n_k}\simeq l^p$.

Comment: Thanks sir, for the answer. But if I take $n_k$ to be the sequence of all even numbers then $l^p_{2n}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $l^p$? In this example can you please tell me what kind of linear transformation will work?

Comment: Yes, $\ell_{n_k}^p \simeq \ell^p$ for any injective sequence $n_k :\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$.  $$\ell^p \to \ell_{n_k}^p : \sum_k \alpha_ke_k \mapsto \sum_k \alpha_ke_{n_k}$$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I got it.